# How can I combine a comparison and an update in one atomic operation?

Tags: linux, x86-64, atomic, c11

I have two threads, which will execute:

```
_Atomic volatile uint64_t foo;

// returns 1 if it updated foo, 0 if fool already had the new value 
int try_to_update_foo(uint64_t new) {
    if (foo < new) {
        foo = new;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want the `foo < new` comparison and `foo = new` assignment operations to be one atomic operation.

i.e. If two threads both try to update foo to the **same** new value, one must return 1 and the other must returns 0.  (It doesn't matter which way around.)

Can I make this work in C11, without involving semaphores/mutexs?

Comment: Would use of `atomic_compare_exchange_weak()` solve your problem?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski So, I would use atomic_compare_exchange_weak() in place of the assignment, and return either 1 or 0 from inside the `if` condition, depending on whether this thread did the exchange?  Should I care that it's "weak"?

Comment: There's strong version too. See the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `atomic_compare_exchange_weak()` or `atomic_compare_exchange_strong()`:

```
#include <stdatomic.h>

_Atomic uint64_t foo;

int try_to_update_foo(uint64_t new) {
    uint64_t expected = atomic_load(&foo);
    while (expected < new) {
        if (atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&foo, &expected, new)) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

See docs for details: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/atomic_compare_exchange

Comment: If another thread set `foo = new` (via this function) while this thread was between the `atomic_load()` and the `atomic_comp...()`, how would this thread return zero to say that it wasn't this thread which did the update?

Comment: @fadedbee, The cmpxchg would fail, because the value changed after the load. Then the next iteration, expected is not less than new, so it returns 0. (Note that the cmpxchg  updates the value of expected to the current value of foo.)

Comment: Since you're looping, you should use `compare_exchange_weak`.  You don't care whether failure was spurious or not, so don't make LL/SC machines use a nested loop to retry internally in that case.  But yes, a CAS retry loop is the way to synthesize any atomic RMW, including this `max` operation.  (@fadedbee).  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap shows how you could use it to emulate `fetch_add` (in a way that's slower on machines that natively support atomic add, so don't actually use that, but the principle is the same for anything.)

Comment: Corrected the code in answer.